# AWK использовать в качестве разделителя /

Tags: linux, ubuntu, консоль, awk

Дан путь к файлу

`./Folder/database/data.txt`

Я пытаюсь вычленить названия папок или файлов, используя разделитель `/`

```
awk -F '/' '{print $NF}'
```

или

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="/"} {print $NF}'
```

Выводит то же самое:

`./Folder/database/data.txt`

В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: Забавно .... У меня `awk -F '/'  '{print $NF}'`
`./Folder/database/data.txt` печатает `data.txt`  / ( версия `awk --vers
GNU Awk 4.1.4, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 4.0.1, GNU MP 6.1.2)`)

Comment: @avp спасибо, помогла перезагрузка :D